# How can i get list of comments at once from this JSON and pass it to recyclerview adapter

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview, retrofit, retrofit2

I am able to fetch comment body from JSON but it is displaying only last element from each comment body and not the complete list of comment body, so how can I get the list if comment body to display it in android recycler view

i have created success story model class in which i have included comments model as an inner class which have some attributes which i want top display but at the end it is only displaying last elements of the body of the comment rather the displaying entire comment as a list on recyclerview adapter

```
[
    {
        "id": "2",
        "pic": "https://amraenterprises.com/heenahealth/uploads/story/06112019110550newyear.jpg",
        "caption": "New Year's Day, also simply called New Year or New Year's, is observed on January 1, the first day of the year on the modern Gregorian calendar as well as the Julian calendar. ",
        "story_count": 3,
        "story_count_comment": 2,
        "comments": [
            {
                "commentid": "1",
                "postid": "2",
                "commenttext": "It's awesome. Thanks for giving us this information.",
                "userid": "4",
                "username": "lorem",
                "isreply": "false",
                "replyto": "-1",
                "type": "story"
            },
            {
                "commentid": "4",
                "postid": "2",
                "commenttext": "Always welcome :)",
                "userid": "1",
                "username": "admin",
                "isreply": "true",
                "replyto": "1",
                "type": "story"
            }
        ]
    }


]
```

My Adapter code

```
class CommentAdapter(private val context: Context, private val successCommentModel: List<SuccessStoryModel>,private val mPos : String) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CommentAdapter.RecyclerViewAdapter>() {



    override fun onCreateViewHolder(viewGroup: ViewGroup, i: Int): RecyclerViewAdapter {

        val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_comment, viewGroup, false)

        return RecyclerViewAdapter(view)

    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerViewAdapter, pos: Int) {

            if(successCommentModel[pos].comments != null)
            {
                if(successCommentModel[pos].comments!![pos].postid == mPos)
                {

                    for(i in 0 until successCommentModel[pos].comments!!.size )
                    {
                        holder.user_name.text = "${successCommentModel[i].comments!![pos].username}"

                        holder.user_comment.text = "${successCommentModel[i].comments!![pos].commenttext}"

                    }


                }
                else
                {
                    holder.user_comment.visibility = View.GONE
                    holder.user_name.visibility = View.GONE
                    holder.no_user_comment.visibility = View.GONE

                }
            }
            else
            {
                holder.user_comment.visibility = View.GONE
                holder.user_name.visibility = View.GONE
                holder.no_user_comment.visibility = View.VISIBLE

            }






    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return successCommentModel.size
    }






}
```

This is Model code for a Success story and comment

````
class SuccessStoryModel {



    @SerializedName("comments")
    @Expose
    var comments: List<CommentModel>? = null



   inner class CommentModel {

        @SerializedName("commentid")
        @Expose
        var commentid: String? = null
        @SerializedName("postid")
        @Expose
        var postid: String? = null
        @SerializedName("commenttext")
        @Expose


    }
}

```
````

Comment: Can you please provide the code that you already wrote?

Comment: Post code you are using, I hope you have added loop for adding comment in a list and that list is created outside the loop and added elements inside the loop.

Comment: Your problem is in your Adapter.

Comment: so can i get the solution for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to pass `List<CommentModel>` in your adapter and implement accordingly. Check below:

```
class CommentAdapter(private val context: Context, private val comments: List<CommentModel>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CommentAdapter.RecyclerViewAdapter>() {



    override fun onCreateViewHolder(viewGroup: ViewGroup, i: Int): RecyclerViewAdapter {

        val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_comment, viewGroup, false)

        return RecyclerViewAdapter(view)

    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerViewAdapter, pos: Int) {

        val comment = comments[pos]

        holder.user_name.text = "${comment.username}"
        holder.user_comment.text = "${comment.commenttext}"

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return comments.size
    }
}
```

Comment: We can always use Gson in these things as Gson will directly give the data model required

Comment: @ROHITLIEN, I know that. Personally I also use that. But I don't know whether he is familiar  or not with the library. That's why I added basic process. Later he posted the model and I see he use it. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @darshankomu, Try to update your adapter according my answer and pass `List<CommentModel>` instead of `List<SuccessStoryModel>` and check. Let me know about the update

Comment: By the way thanks for the help @Md. Asaduzzaman **I got the solution error was instead of List<CommentModel> or List<SuccessStoryModel> I have used List<SuccessStoryModel.CommentModel>** if anyone has any other better solution for this problem then they are most welcome

Comment: Actually `List<CommentModel>` and `List<SuccessStoryModel.CommentModel>` are same. Since you are using inner class then you have to write like this way **parentClass.innerClass**

Comment: My answer is correct bro. If you think it's ok then accept it. It's up to you. Thanks

Comment: Atually whenever i call my adapter that is CommentAdapter it is always starting from 0 position and set the data accordingly on RecyclerView but i want to get only specific postion data from adapter to set it on RecyclerView how can this will be possible

Comment: Inside this onBindViewHolder  pos it set data is always from 0th postion i wat to set data from any postion from my JSON array how can this will be possible `override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerViewAdapter, pos: Int) {

        Toast.makeText(context, successCommentModel[pos].postid + mPos, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

        holder.user_name.text = "${successCommentModel[pos].username}"
        holder.user_comment.text = "${successCommentModel[pos].commenttext}"

    }`

Answer (score 0):

The solution may be in your adapter for the recyclerview, you have to handle every elements